# Gitlab : How to push code into my branch in Eclipse Git Plugin

Tags: android, version-control, eclipse-plugin, gitlab

Am using Gitlab for SCM .  How to push code into my branch in Eclipse Git Plugin. Only option is available is commit & push . Any option to commit and push later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry to say that, but the best tool to manage git is command line. Linux and mac are the best to do so. Although they have a good GUI Tool in windows, the best way to manage git is through command line.

So the sequence should be:

`git pull //update everything on your local code 
git add . //To add changes
git commit -m "This is my commentary" //To commit
git push //To upload changes to server`